# Configuring different language keyboard layouts for programs

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmonad

I'm currently on Ubuntu 12.04 using xmonad.

In a ~/.xsessionrc I've got the following configuration for different keyboard language layouts:

```
setxkbmap -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,ctrl:nocaps" -layout "us,ru"
```

Everything works fine. But I'd like to configure the layout switching in such a manner that for different program I can set different layout.

For example, right now, while in a Chrome typing in a blog post with a Russian letters, I switch to a command line, but it is in Cyrillic, and I need it to be in English/Latin.

Would greatly appreciate if you can point me to the right direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you check `xxkb`.